# Deck of Cards in Batch

Tags: batch-file

This card deck script always starts at the same card when I run it, but shuffles the rest. How can I tweak it so that the first card drawn is always different as well?

```
@echo off
title 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set a=0
set e=52
set f=0
for %%a in (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A) do call :a "%%a"
goto c
:a arg1
set b= %~1
for %%b in (%~1D%b%C%b%H%b%S) do call :b "%%b"
exit /b 0
:b arg1
set /a a=a+1
set Card%a%=%~1
exit /b 0
:c
set /a c=%random%*%e%/32768+1
set d=!Card%c%!
set /a f=%f%+1
echo Card #%f%: %d%
echo.
pause
cls
set Card%c%=!Card%e%!
set /a e=%e%-1
if %e% neq 0 goto c

exit
```

Comment: So is the question actually related to this piece of code, or do you just want to know how to get a random number between 1 and 52 using batch?

Comment: And... *why batch*? It can only barely be called a programming language, and doesn't even have obvious things like arrays.

Comment: @GregHewgill Because it's fun! Batch games really challenge the mind.

Comment: So does Haskell, for example, and you might actually learn something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set d=!Card%c%!
```

You would want to write something like %Card%c%%, but that obviously doesn't work, because you will get the contents of the (non-existent) variable 'Card', a constant 'c' and a constant '%'.

`!` is an alternative to `%` for indicating a variable. It is used for 'delayed expansion'. This basically causes a variable to be evaluated at execution time instead of parse time. It is explained in more detail here: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Now, the delaying isn't *that* important, because the parser could just evaluate the variable from inside out. But the problem is that it doesn't know that a % sign indicates an inner variable. It just thinks it is the end for the variable 'Card'. So by using two different characters, you help the parser understand what is going on.

But for this to work, you need to enable delayed expansion, which is what the first line does.

Comment: This worked well, but the number generator is apparently disfunctional because it only displays one answer and not a random once upon each execution.

Also, could you elaborate on why the exclamation points work?

Comment: Sure. I've added an explanation to my answer. I hope I described it properly, since I haven't used this technique very often, so I hope I understood it correctly myself. ;)

Comment: You explanation was perfect, thank you! But how may I fix the random generation bug?

Answer (score 2):

I would not use an array to represent the cards. Instead I would use a single variable containing a space delimited list of cards. It is then easy to select a random card via substring operations and a random position number. The deck is shortened each time a card is chosen. In this way it is easy to always pick a random card from those that are still available.

Here are some simple routines to build a deck of cards, and then shuffle the deck. The suit and values are parameterized, so it is easy to construct various types of decks. It should be easy to add routines to deal out hands, draw cards, etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

call :buildDeck "D C H S" "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 J Q K A"
echo deck=%deck%

call :shuffleDeck
echo shuffledDeck=%deck%

exit /b

:buildDeck  suitList  valueList
set "deck="
set "deckSize=0"
for %%S in (%~1) do for %%C in (%~2) do (
  set "deck=!deck!%%C%%S "
  set /a deckSize+=1
)
exit /b

:shuffleDeck
setlocal
set "shuffled="
for /l %%N in (%deckSize% -1 1) do (
  set /a "pos=!random! %% %%N * 3, rest=pos+3"
  for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in ("!pos! !rest!") do (
    set "shuffled=!shuffled!!deck:~%%A,3!"
    set "deck=!deck:~0,%%A!!deck:~%%B!"
  )
)
endlocal & set "deck=%shuffled%"
exit /b
```

**UPDATE (now debugged)**

Woops - I forgot 10. As the OP suggests, I could use T to represent 10, but that is not ideal. I could use 10 and then add extra spaces as needed to have every card represented as 4 characters instead of 3, but instead I've opted to revert to an array for the initial card definitions, and then strings for the shuffled deck and hands.

I've also added routines to deal, discard, and draw cards. There is still plenty to do to turn this into a functional game, but it should be enough to get you moving in the right direction.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define and shuffle deck and show result
echo Shuffle deck
call :defineCards "D C H S" "2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A"
call :shuffleDeck
echo deck=%deck%

echo(
pause
echo(

:: Deal 5 cards to 4 players
echo deal
call :deal "player1 player2 player3 player4" 5
:: show result
set player
echo deck=%deck%

echo(
pause
echo(

:: Have player1 discard the 1st and 3rd cards by value.
:: First get the list of cards to discard programatically, but it could be via user input
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%A in ("!player1!") do set "discard=%%A %%B"
:: Now discard the cards and show the result
echo Player1 discards %discard%
call :discard player1 "%discard%"
set player
echo deck=%deck%

echo(
pause
echo(

:: Have player1 draw 2 cards and show result
echo Player1 draws 2 cards
call :draw player1 2
set player
echo deck=%deck%

echo(
echo That's all for now :-)
exit /b


:defineCards  suitList  valueList
for %%S in (%~1) do for %%C in (%~2) do (
  set /a card.count+=1
  set "card.!card.count!=%%C%%S"
)
exit /b

:shuffleDeck
setlocal
set "deck="
for /l %%N in (%card.count% -1 1) do (
  set /a "R=!random! %% %%N + 1, card.count-=1"
  for %%I in (!R!) do set "deck=!deck! !card.%%I!"
  for /l %%I in (!R! 1 !card.count!) do (
    set /a "J=%%I+1"
    for %%J in (!J!) do set "card.%%I=!card.%%J!"
  )
)
endlocal & set "deck=%deck%"
exit /b

:deal  playerList  cardCount
for /l %%N in (1 1 %2) do for %%P in (%~1) do (
  for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("!deck!") do (
    set "%%P=!%%P! %%A"
    set "deck=%%B"
  )
)
exit /b

:discard  player  cardList
for %%C in (%~2) do set "%1=!%1: %%C=!"
exit /b

:draw  player  cardCount
for /l %%N in (1 1 %2) do for /f "tokens=1*" %%A in ("!deck!") do (
  set "%1=!%1! %%A"
  set "deck=%%B"
)
```

-- Sample output --

```
Shuffle deck
deck= JC 2C 9H 9S QC 5C 4S AC KD 7S 8C 10D 10H 5S 3S 3C AD 10C 10S 4H 7C 4C AH QS 2H QH 7D KH 6H KC 4D 6D 8S 9C 8D JD 6C JS 7H 3H 3D 2S JH KS 9D 6S AS 5H 2D 5D 8H QD

Press any key to continue . . .

deal
player1= JC QC KD 10H AD
player2= 2C 5C 7S 5S 10C
player3= 9H 4S 8C 3S 10S
player4= 9S AC 10D 3C 4H
deck=7C 4C AH QS 2H QH 7D KH 6H KC 4D 6D 8S 9C 8D JD 6C JS 7H 3H 3D 2S JH KS 9D 6S AS 5H 2D 5D 8H QD

Press any key to continue . . .

Player1 discards JC KD
player1= QC 10H AD
player2= 2C 5C 7S 5S 10C
player3= 9H 4S 8C 3S 10S
player4= 9S AC 10D 3C 4H
deck=7C 4C AH QS 2H QH 7D KH 6H KC 4D 6D 8S 9C 8D JD 6C JS 7H 3H 3D 2S JH KS 9D 6S AS 5H 2D 5D 8H QD

Press any key to continue . . .

Player1 draws 2 cards
player1= QC 10H AD 7C 4C
player2= 2C 5C 7S 5S 10C
player3= 9H 4S 8C 3S 10S
player4= 9S AC 10D 3C 4H
deck=AH QS 2H QH 7D KH 6H KC 4D 6D 8S 9C 8D JD 6C JS 7H 3H 3D 2S JH KS 9D 6S AS 5H 2D 5D 8H QD

That's all for now :-)
```

Comment: How do I draw only one card? And also, is there any way to integrate '10' or will I just have to use 'T' for 10?

Comment: OMG, that is embarrassing, I forgot how to count! "T" would certainly work, but let me think about it and see if I can come up with a better solution.

Comment: @user3093536 - OK, I've got a solution that works with 10 - I've reverted back to using an array. It could be done with strings if card definitions are padded with spaces to width of 4 instead of 3. shuffling the array is more complicated, but it is more flexible as it lends itself to varying string lengths. I've also added additional routines. The rest is up to you.

Comment: I noticed that in your sample output, the shuffled deck has repeating cards towards the end, which is a problem I faced while using my previous script. Will this change as more cards are drawn or is this a bug?

Comment: @user3093536 - Oh man, you got me again :-) In my haste to finish up and get to bed last night, I didn't look close enough at my results, and I had a silly but serious bug in :shuffle. All fixed now.

Comment: I feel like I might not be able to create a P1 vs. CP card game from this due to the lack of order in cards from strongest to weakest, so I decided to stick to my previous method. However, I face the problem of the first card drawn being constant. Could you assist me in this, please?

Answer (score 1):

If these commands:

```
set /a c=%random%*52/32768+1
set d=!Card%c%!
```

are placed inside a `for` loop or `if` command, then you must use:

```
set /a c=!random!*52/32768+1
for %%c in ("!c!") do set d=!Card%%~c!
```

for the same reasons given in the previous answer...

Comment: This actually did not help me much in the for loop, am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: If you use `set /a c=%random%*52/32768+1` inside a `for` loop you get _the same answer_ N times, and the way to fix it is via the code in my solution. Check that the _other parts_ of your code are working correctly...

Comment: I'm going by what you said now, but could you help me correct my script, please?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to make the first card random? Try this...

```
@echo off
title
rem %random%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set a=0
set e=52
set f=0
for %%a in (2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K A) do call :a "%%a"
goto c
:a arg1
set b= %~1
for %%b in (%~1D%b%C%b%H%b%S) do call :b "%%b"
exit /b 0
:b arg1
set /a a=a+1
set Card%a%=%~1
exit /b 0
:c
set /a c=%random%*%e%/32768+1
set d=!Card%c%!
set /a f=%f%+1
echo Card #%f%: %d%
echo.
pause
cls
set Card%c%=!Card%e%!
set /a e=%e%-1
if %e% neq 0 goto c

exit
```

I just put in "rem %random%". Voila.